# Bloquear texto no textBox

Tags: javascript

Bom dia gente.. 
Tenho essa máscara feita e preciso que ela bloqueie texto no campo textBox da minha aplicação, mas não consigo imaginar em algum jeito pra fazer isso. (noob)
Alguém poderia me ajudar?

```
function Mascara(src, mascara) {
    try{

        var campo = src.value.length;
        var saida = mascara.substring(0, 1);
        var texto = mascara.substring(campo);
        if(texto.substring(0, 1) != saida) {
            src.value += texto.substring(0, 1);
        }
    }catch (e){
        ExibeMens ("Ocorreu exceção durante execução !" + e.description, true);
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Podes explicar melhor o que é `ExibeMens` e o que queres dizer com "bloqueie texto no campo textBox da minha aplicação"? podes colocar HTML que estás a usar?

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="text" id="exemplo" value="Exemplo" disabled />
```

Depois que você aplicar a máscara coloque para o campo inputText ser desativado com o `disable` com o seguinte jQuery: `$("#exemplo").attr("disabled","disabled")`

Espero ter te ajudado!

Comment: **disabled = true** não funciona com inputs, por qualquer que seja o motivo. O correto é **disabled = "disabled"**. Dessa forma, seu exemplo deveria ser editado para $("#exemplo").attr("disabled","disabled")

Answer (score -1):

Se você usar o `readonly` no `input text` não permitirá a edição, apenas leitura como o próprio atributo diz.

`<input type="text" readonly name="texto">`

Comment: Produção, tomei -1 aqui.